# python regular expression replacing part of a matched string

Tags: python, regex, string

i got an string that might look like this

```
"myFunc('element','node','elementVersion','ext',12,0,0)"
```

i'm currently checking for validity using, which works fine

```
myFunc\((.+?)\,(.+?)\,(.+?)\,(.+?)\,(.+?)\,(.+?)\,(.+?)\)
```

now i'd like to replace whatever string is at the 3rd parameter.
unfortunately i cant just use a stringreplace on whatever sub-string on the 3rd position since the same 'sub-string' could be anywhere else in that string.

with this and a re.findall,

```
myFunc\(.+?\,.+?\,(.+?)\,.+?\,.+?\,.+?\,.+?\)
```

i was able to get the contents of the substring on the 3rd position, but re.sub does not replace the string it just returns me the string i want to replace with :/

here's my code

```
myRe = re.compile(r"myFunc\(.+?\,.+?\,(.+?)\,.+?\,.+?\,.+?\,.+?\)")
val =   "myFunc('element','node','elementVersion','ext',12,0,0)"

print myRe.findall(val)
print myRe.sub("noVersion",val)
```

any idea what i've missed ?

thanks!
Seb

Comment: The variety of answers here leads me to believe that the Pythonic revolt against Perl's TIMTOWTDI motto was somewhat misguided. :)

Answer (score 9):

In re.sub, you need to specify a substitution for the whole matching string. That means that you need to repeat the parts that you don't want to replace. This works:

```
myRe = re.compile(r"(myFunc\(.+?\,.+?\,)(.+?)(\,.+?\,.+?\,.+?\,.+?\))")
print myRe.sub(r'\1"noversion"\3', val)
```

Answer (score 4):

If your only tool is a hammer, all problems look like nails. A regular expression is a powerfull hammer but is not the best tool for every task.

Some tasks are better handled by a parser. In this case the argument list in the string is just like a Python tuple, sou you can cheat: use the Python builtin parser:

```
>>> strdata = "myFunc('element','node','elementVersion','ext',12,0,0)"
>>> args = re.search(r'\(([^\)]+)\)', strdata).group(1)
>>> eval(args)
('element', 'node', 'elementVersion', 'ext', 12, 0, 0)
```

If you can't trust the input [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is safer than eval for this. Once you have the argument list in the string decontructed I think you can figure out how to manipulate and reassemble it again, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation: `re.sub` returns a copy of the string where every occurrence of the entire pattern is replaced with the replacement. It cannot in any case modify the original string, because Python strings are immutable.

Try using look-ahead and look-behind assertions to construct a regex that only matches the element itself:

```
myRe = re.compile(r"(?<=myFunc\(.+?\,.+?\,)(.+?)(?=\,.+?\,.+?\,.+?\,.+?\))")
```

Comment: If there is some chance of an argument containing a comma, the regex approach gets harder and harder.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using named groups? http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace

Hopefully that will let you just target the 3rd match.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without using regex:

```
>>> s = "myFunc('element','node','elementVersion','ext',12,0,0)"
>>> l = s.split(",")
>>> l[2]="'noVersion'"
>>> s = ",".join(l)
>>> s
"myFunc('element','node','noVersion','ext',12,0,0)"
```

Comment: what if first arg is 'ele,ment' ?

Comment: Then, all the answers, including the regular expression ones, fail. :)

Comment: you are right! that is why I think a parser is best suited to this task than a regular expression.

Comment: @Paulo, Yes, parsers, if available for the work at hand, should be preferred over regex.