# How to replace this string with re.sub?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Assume two strings, `foo.example.com/1.2.3/sdk-foo-bar.min.js` and `foo.example.com/1.2.3/sdk-foo-bar-dev.min.js`.

By default, the first one is used in the HTML code, but depending on a parameter, I need to replace it with the second (i.e. add the `-dev`).

I have a regex already (`foo\.example\.com/1\.2\.3/(sdk-foo-bar).min\.js`) that looks for the string and captures the group `sdk-foo-bar`, but how can I now replace this group with `sdk-foo-bar-dev`??

Comment: Capture what you need to keep: `re.sub(r'(foo\.example\.com/1\.2\.3/)sdk-foo-bar(\.min\.js)', r'\1sdk-foo-bar-dev\2', s)`

Comment: Here is the answer with the [same idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4489152/3832970).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inp = 'foo.example.com/1.2.3/sdk-foo-bar.min.js'

m = re.search('(^.*)(.min.js)', inp)
if m:
    print ('%s-%s%s' % (m.group(1), 'dev', m.group(2)))
```